# Reset Jest mock of id generator on every test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I'm trying to mock id generation function.
Content of my `generateIdsSet.js` file is:

```
import nanoid from 'nanoid/generate'

const generateId = (): string => {
  return nanoid('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 5)
}

export const generateIdsSet = (setLength) => {
  const setIds = []

  for (let i = 0; i < setLength; i++) {
    setIds.push(generateId())
  }

  return setIds
}
```

In the mock file `generateIdsSet.spec.js` for `generateIdsSet` I need to create array of predictable ids. I came up with that implementation:

```
import { generateIdsSet } from './generateIdsSet.js'

jest.mock('nanoid/generate', () => {
  let value = 0

  return () => String(++value)
})

describe('generateIdsSet', () => {
  it('One element', () => {
    expect(generateIdsSet(1)).toEqual(['1'])
  })

  it('Four elements', () => {
    expect(generateIdsSet(4)).toEqual(['1', '2', '3', '4'])
  })

  ....
})
```

Everything is OK except that on every test counter doesn't reset to 1 and keeps incrementing for every call.

Maybe it's something obvious I'm missing but I can't figure it out. I will be grateful for the help.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to mock an ES import you need to also import the module in the test file. There are multiple ways of doing this, but the two easiest ways are:

- Use `autoMock` and create a `__mock__` directory adjacent to the test (adds boilerplate)
- Import the module you want to mock in the file (easier)

```
import nanoid from 'nanoid/generate'
import { generateIdsSet } from './generateIdsSet.js'

jest.mock('nanoid')

nanoid.mockImplementation(() => {
  let value = 0

  return () => String(++value)
});

afterAll(() => {
  // don't forget to restore when done!
  nanoid.mockRestore()
});

describe('generateIdsSet', () => {
  it('One element', () => {
    expect(generateIdsSet(1)).toEqual(['1'])
  })

  it('Four elements', () => {
    expect(generateIdsSet(4)).toEqual(['1', '2', '3', '4'])
  })

  ....
})
```

More mocking goodness can be found [in this medium article](https://medium.com/@rickhanlonii/understanding-jest-mocks-f0046c68e53c) (note, I am *not* the author).